# Show that the topology on $X$ is contained in the Box topology on $X$

Tags: general-topology

I have been searching and searching through the Munkres Topology book for examples and trying to understand how to do this problem but I have had no luck as of yet. If someone could help out it would be much appreciated!

Let
$A$ be a set and ${X_α},α∈A$ a family of topological spaces. Denote by $X$ the product
$α∈A$, $X_α$.

1. Show that the product topology on $X$ is contained in the box topology on $X$.
2. Show that if $A$ is finite, then the product and box topologies are equal.
3. Show that for infinite $A$, if $X_α = X_β$ for all $α, β ∈ A$, then the diagonal map
   $\Delta: X_α \to X$ is not necessarily continuous with respect to the box topology.

Comment: We need some more context here. What are your thoughts on the problem? Do you know the definitions of the product and box topologies? Which definitions do you use?

Comment: Define in detail that supposed diagonal map.

Comment: The first two are just definitions. Maybe you can try to write out the definitions of bases of these two topology explicitly, and try to see what is the difference